# Show vs ShowDialog. Can Dialogs be hidden by the user?

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, modeless

In Windows Mobile, if I do a call to Show rather than ShowDialog I will get a modeless dialog box.

If that modeless dialog fills the whole screen, is there a way to switch out to a different screen?  (Kind of like Alt + Tab in windows).

I need to make sure that the modeless screen is locked in place till the OK in the upper right corner is pressed or a menu item that I have made.  (To see why I need to do this see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105438/how-to-attach-messages-from-a-form-shown-with-showdialog-to-application2) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105438/how-to-attach-messages-from-a-form-shown-with-showdialog-to-application2/3105962#3105962).)

Does any one know a way to switch modeless screens with out closing the screen (so I can stop it)?  (Once it closes I can take care of it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can use the hardware buttons (quick launch, voice recorder, etc) buttons to change apps, which would bring another Form forward, but they can do that even with a modal dialog up.

"Switching" screens should be as simple as calling Show on the one you want brought to the fore.

Comment: Sounds good.  I just wanted to make sure that there was not some way to move between open modeless dialogs in an app.